# how can I find the original work on the bases of which 2016 nobel in economics was given?

Tags: contract-theory

I have been google and googling and asking around and I can not find the work(s) on the basis of which the nobel in economics was given yesterday. I really wanted to read them. does anyone know how to find it?

Answer (score 3):

It is based on multiple pieces of work, most of which can be found in the prize [committee's thoroughly referenced announcement](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-sciences/laureates/2016/advanced-economicsciences2016.pdf).